# HASHBYTES() result of another HASHBYTES(), OR CHECKSUM_AGG() aggregate for HASHBYTES()?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, hashing

I want to aggregate a single HASHBYTES() from the results of another HASHBYTES()... something like CHECKSUM_AGG() does for CHECKSUM()...

I have been able find how to make a single HASH per row of columns from a table:

```
SELECT 
    hashbytes('MD5', (
            SELECT SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
                ,SPECIFIC_NAME
                ,ROUTINE_SCHEMA
                ,ROUTINE_NAME
                ,ROUTINE_TYPE
                ,ROUTINE_DEFINITION
            FROM (
                VALUES (NULL)
                ) foo(bar)
            FOR XML auto
            )) AS [Hash]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES AS MBT;
```

How do I aggregate to a single hash from all the hash rows returned?

(Yes, I want to reduce a table to a single hash for comparison to table(s) in other databases).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT` to concatenate all the columns per row, then `STRING_AGG` to concatenate the whole table, and hash the result.

How reliable such a hash would be in the face of collisions, I couldn't say. `MD5` is deprecated anyway, you should use `SHA2_512`

```sql
SELECT 
    HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',
      STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
        CAST(SPECIFIC_SCHEMA AS nvarchar(max))  -- at least one '(max)'
       ,SPECIFIC_NAME
       ,ROUTINE_SCHEMA
       ,ROUTINE_NAME
       ,ROUTINE_TYPE
       ,ROUTINE_DEFINITION
       ), '')) AS [hash]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES AS MBT;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=913afbb5d539c4bea25aa81f6997d575)

Why you are using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` as opposed to `sys.procedures` is a different question. Is it just an example?

Comment: it is just a useful example... I am trying to write a HASHBYTES() version of the CHECKSUM()/CHECKSUM_AGG() script I like from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311969/check-for-changes-to-a-sql-server-database

Comment: The `STRING_AGG` needs a `WITHIN_GROUP ORDER BY <something unique>` to produce a deterministic hash. Also, if the table is large, this solution ends up building an extremely large string in memory.